# Alternative to partial dependence plot?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, error-handling, scikit-learn, deprecated

as far as I can see, `sklearn` has deprecated the [partial dependence functionality](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_partial_dependence.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-partial-dependence-py). I tried to run a simple example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import partial_dependence
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence

X, y = make_friedman1()
clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=10).fit(X, y)
plot_partial_dependence(clf, X, [0, (0, 1)])
```

But I am returned the following error message: `ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.inspection'`

To me, partial dependence (and marginal effects) plots a very important (in combination with relative importances) to better understand machine learning results and predictions.

Is there an alternative available? Respectively, how can I plot the partial dependence?

Comment: have you found the cause of this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Haven’t. Still unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a confusion with versions of `sklearn`. Just as a suggestion -- I would check yours (e.g., `import sklearn; sklearn.__version__`). For example, if it is [v.0.20.3](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence.partial_dependence.html#sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence.partial_dependence), by chance -- aren't you looking for `partial_dependence` and `plot_partial_dependence` from `sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence` instead of `sklearn.inspection`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by simply updating sklearn, which now contains sklearn.inspection. I'm using Anaconda, if you're also using Anaconda, simply type this in the Anaconda Propmt:

```
conda update --all
```

to update all packages. Restart your jupyter notebook and now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import partial_dependence
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay

X, y = make_friedman1()
clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=10).fit(X, y)
PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(clf, X, [0, (0, 1)])
```